# Why my SFML program hangs and then terminates?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to run this simple SFML program but it behaves in a rather weird way. The window is rendering but I can't close it. After some time my program terminates. I'm using SFML 2.4.2 and GNU compiler.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
int main() 
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Test");
    while(window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }

            window.clear();
            window.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a missing `break` after `window.close();`

Comment: @VTT it's still hanging even with `break`

Comment: Actually a `break` isn't needed. Try running under a debugger to see if any exception is raised.

Comment: @rustyx it's terminated with exit value: -1 073 741 515

Comment: I converted it to hex and is 0xc0000135 but then googling for that the result says "program can't start because of a missing dll" I don't think that applies since the application is running.